# Expressjs Not Sending Response After POST Request

Tags: javascript, express

I have this function on the express side:

```
// Register user login
exports.register_user = function(req, res) {
    var portalID = req.body.portalID;
    var companyName = req.body.companyName;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var password2 = req.body.password2;

    var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(12);
    var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);
    password = hash;

    var params = {
        TableName: "HouseAccounts",
        Item: {
            "portalID": portalID,
            "companyName": companyName,
            "points": 0,
            "password": password,
        }
    }
    res.sendStatus(200);
}
```

And this fetch on the front end:

```
function register() {
  fetch("MyURL/register", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      "portalID": document.getElementById("portal-id").value,
      "companyName": document.getElementById("company-name").value,
      "password": document.getElementById("password").value,
      "password2": document.getElementById("password2").value
    })
  }).then(function(response){console.log(response)});
}
```

On the express side I can receive the JSON that was sent through the POST and do stuff with that data. However, on my front end I am not receiving a response back from the express side. The connection times out and status is `(failed)` with error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch` in the console.

Comment: This may have already been solved previously. have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42754388/uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-failed-to-fetch-and-cors-error

Comment: @JackJefferies Yes, I've tried logging response.json() but I do not receive anything back from the api call at all.

Comment: coz you are sending nothing. just a `200` response header. no data is being sent from server side

Comment: Anything in the server log? No error?
What happens when you send `res.json(...)` just as a test?

Comment: @FabianTe figured it out

Comment: @UsmanRana res.sendStatus(200) is equivalent to res.status(200).send('OK').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the problem was I am working on AWS Cloud9 and my Public IP to access the API changed upon restarting the instance so the request was not reaching the server side at all.