# Fetch throws "TypeError: Failed to fetch" for successful, same-origin request

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

We have been encountering inconsistent client errors with a single-page JavaScript application making fetch requests. Of note, they are all *same-origin* requests.

```
let request = new Request(url, options);
...
window.fetch(request)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => ...)
  .catch(error => ...)
```

Around 5% of the promises are rejecting with the following error despite the server and the browser receiving a `200 OK` response:

```
TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

I'm stumped... All of my searches lead to discussions about CORS errors. That doesn't seem to apply given these are all same-origin requests. What is causing the fetch to throw the `TypeError`?

I can confirm using the Network tab in Chrome DevTools that the fetch request completes with a `200 OK` response and valid JSON. I can also confirm that the URLs are same-origin. I can also confirm that there are no CORS pre-flight requests. I have reproduced this issue on Chrome 66 and Safari 11.1. However, we've received a stream of error reports from a mix of Chrome and Safari versions, both desktop and mobile.

---

EDIT:

This does not appear to be a duplicate of the linked question as we are *not* sending CORS requests, *not* setting `mode: "no-cors"`, and *not* setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Additionally, I re-ran tests with the `mode: 'same-origin'` option set explicitly. The requests are (still) successful; however, we (still) receive the intermittent `TypeError`.

Comment: Are you using `mode: "no-cors"` in the `options`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42754388/uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-failed-to-fetch-and-cors-error?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @Barmar I do *not* set the `mode` option. It looks as though the default `mode` is `cors` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode). Not sure what that means in the context of a same-origin request. However, I can re-test and update the thread by using `mode: same-origin` explicitly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch and Cors error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42754388/uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-failed-to-fetch-and-cors-error)

Comment: @Mr.White I read through that question... The accepted answer talks about CORS headers and pre-flight requests. These don't occur with my same-origin request. Additionally, the comments on the question have the *real* answer to that question: "I think all your problems will go away if you remove the access-control header from the request and don't add mode: 'no-cors' to the request". I have confirmed that this is how my requests are constructed.

Comment: I haven't been able to find any other explanation of this error that doesn't involve that option.

Comment: Yes. I'm very curious about explicitly setting `mode: "same-origin"` on the request. Trying it now. Interestingly, the spec indicates the default mode is "no-cors" (https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-mode) as opposed to the MDN docs that say it's "cors".

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @AndyFurniss Unfortunately, no. We ended up re-writing our HTTP layer using RxJS. (We still use `fetch`, but all of the promises are wrapped up in an observable.) During that process, this issue disappeared. Sorry.

Comment: @seniorquico No worries. Thanks for getting back to me. Glad you got around it in the end.

Comment: It only said `Failed to fetch` and that's it?

Comment: As I recall, the info posted above was everything available at the time. The error was simply `TypeError: Failed to fetch`, and the Network tab in the Chrome DevTools confirmed the browser received a valid response. It looked like a typical CORS error, but these were same origin requests (all going to the same server!!!). As noted in my edit, the problem disappeared after we reworked our HTTP client layer to RxJS. I am still a little frustrated that we never figured it out!

Comment: I added a bounty because I have the same error, as recorded by Sentry, but it's near impossible to reproduce with any consistency. In my case it's a Next.js application, with `useSWR` for data fetching, wrapped in React Suspense. I have no idea if it's triggered by either the server or client, by interrupting the connection for any reason, and there doesn't seem to be any way to "catch" and "handle" it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting "TypeError: failed to fetch" when the request hasn't actually failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49343024/getting-typeerror-failed-to-fetch-when-the-request-hasnt-actually-failed)

Comment: Had the same problem. After adding `window.addEventListener('offline', function(e) { console.log('offline'); });` I could see it was actually a hardware/network problem: The device was connected via WLAN and sometimes just lost its connection...

Answer (score 8):

I know that this is an old issue, but after searching the entire evening I want to share my findings so you can spend your time better.

My web app also worked well for most users but from time to time visitors received the error mentioned in the question. I'm not using any complicated infrastructure (reverse proxy etc.) setup nor do I communicate with services on a different domain/protocol/port. I'm just sending a POST request to a PHP-File on the same server where the React app is served from.

The short answer: My problem was that I've sent the request to the backend by using an absolute URL, like `https://my-fancy-domain.com/funky_service.php`. After changing this to a relative path like `/funky-service.php` the issue was gone.

My explanation: Most users come to the site without www in the URL, but some users actually do type this part in their address bars (`www.my-fancy...`). It turned out that the **www is part of the origin**, so when these users submit the form and send post requests to https://my-fancy... it's technically another origin. This is why the browser expects CORS headers and sometimes even sends an OPTIONS preflight request. When you use a relative path in your JavaScript-Code the post request will also include the www-part (uses the origin from the address bar) -> same-origin -> no CORS hassle. As it only affects visitors that come with the www to your site it also explains the fact that it worked for most users even with the absolute URL.

Also important to know: The request fails in the browser/ JavaScript-Code but is actually sent to the backend (very ugly!).

Let me know if you need more information. Actually, it is very simple but hard to explain (and to find)

Answer (score -1):

The issue could be with the response you are receiving from back-end. If it was working fine on the server then the problem could be with the response headers. Check the Access-Control-Allow-Origin (ACAO) in the response headers. Usually react's fetch API will throw fail to fetch even after receiving response when the response headers' ACAO and the origin of request won't match.

Ref: [Getting "TypeError: failed to fetch" when the request hasn't actually failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49343024/getting-typeerror-failed-to-fetch-when-the-request-hasnt-actually-failed)

Comment: Yes, great troubleshooting step for CORS applications. In our case, it was a same-origin request.

Comment: Did you go through the link in the comment ?