# fetch data from json running on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I want to fetch data from JSON object which is on my localhost .
..This might be really stupid question but I am beginner in JS.

and is there any other way to fetch data ??

```
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/show')
     .then(result => {
          console.log(result);
          return result.json();
      });
      .then(data => {
         console.log(data);
      });
      .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
      });
```

this http://localhost:3000/show contains json objects.
  it has retrieved data from mongoose.

Comment: Are you asking how to display as tables? If so, what have you tried?

Comment: @openwonk I am unable to fetch data, once i am able to fetch data i willl do it.

Comment: Can you be more clear on your question? From where are you trying to fetch JSON Object? What is running on "http://localhost:3000/"? What is returned from endpoint "/show" when you hit it from your browser?

Comment: @Sreehari Login page is running on my localhost:3000. JSON object is returning from endpoint /show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the semicolons between each `.then` call.

Promises use a kind of "monadic" pattern: each method on a promise returns another promise, which has the same API. This means you can chain promise methods indefinitely.

So:

```
fetch()
.then(/* stuff */)
.then(/* more stuff */)
.catch(/* even more stuff */); // <-- this is the only semicolon
```

The same is true of many Array methods, so you'll often see code like this:

```
Object.keys( someObj )            // returns an array
.map(/* iterator function */)     // Array.map returns an array
.filter(/* iterator function */)  // Array.filter returns an array
.sort(/* comparator function */); // Array.sort returns an array
```

Again, only one semicolon is needed, because each step of the statement produces an array, and JS lets you anticipate that.

---

If that doesn't help, you might want to post the error you're getting.

I should add that `result.json()` will throw if the server at `http://localhost:3000/show` fails to provide the HTTP header `Content-Type: application/json`. Even if the response body is entirely valid JSON, the HTTPResponse class refuses to do `.json()` if the server doesn't state that the content is json.

Also, if this code is running in a browser, and is served from a different host (or port), you will need to do CORS stuff. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48287868/814463 for possible help.

Comment: after removing semicolons and i have a typo error in the catch block, do you mind to change the code and post it ??

Comment: Remove every semicolon. All of them. Then it should work. If it still doesn't, you have a different problem. My guess is that your local server is not returning the proper `Content-Type` HTTP header, although I can't say for sure if you don't say what error you're getting.

Comment: TypeError: Failed to fetch    =>    this is what console is showing. Anyway Thank you man

Comment: i had not installed a package called cors. After installing it , i could fetch data.

Answer (score 0):

If your endpoint '/show' returns the json data without any issue, then the below code should console you the json response.

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/show')
.then(res => {
     console.log(result);
     return res.json()
)}
.then(json => console.log(json))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```