# Fetch JSON file from url in Javascript, React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch, typeerror

I have a problem fetching JSON data from url. I would really appreciate it if you could help me solve this issue.

I wanted to fetch JSON data from firebase storage, but somewhat I can't, so I simplified the code and now it's really simple, but no luck.
I also searched the cause of the error in this community, but I didn't find it.

This is my code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleOnPress}>
          <Text>test</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
  handleOnPress = () => {
    console.log('test was clicked');
    fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data))
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  };
}
```

needless to say, the message, 'test was clicked' is displayed without any problem

Error message

```
Error: "Failed to fetch" in TypeError: Failed to fetch ...
```

I use Expo Snack, web compiler.

Thank you.

Comment: Already resolved : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42754388/uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-failed-to-fetch-and-cors-error

Comment: I put your code into an Expo Snack and it works, can you share the entire Snack you're using? Here's mine - https://snack.expo.io/@hannigan/trembling-almond

Comment: @Corentin de Maupeou Thank you very much. I've tried it once before, but I'll try it again afterwards!

Comment: @Dan Well... This may be because of my network environment... You snack doesn't work in my laptop neither. I still have no idea what's happening...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the error before Failed to fetch: 
`Access to fetch at 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json' from origin 'XXX' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

If so, it is a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors) issue.

If not, feel free to post any other information you are seeing. I'm sure there must be more errors logged than - Failed to Fetch.

Comment: Thank you for replying so quickly! But, I'm afraid that there's no other information nor error code. The console looks like
test was clicked
Error: "Failed to fetch" in TypeError: Failed to fetch ...

Comment: Nothing looks wrong in your Fetch Code. It could be something else. Could you post a link or something?

Comment: Thank you for replying! https://snack.expo.io/@vocabon/e46690

Answer (score 0):

here is 2 methods that using for async fatching data from json file URL with javascript

**using fetch + .then**

```
       function loadUsers_then() {
        let url = '< Your URL Here>';
        try{
        fetch(url)
            .then((response) => { return response.json() })
            .then((data) => {
                for (let curr of data.results) {
                    str += `<Your html string here>`
                }
                document.querySelector('#mydiv').innerHTML = str;
            })
    }}
       catch(err){
            console.log('there was an error', err);
        }
```

**using async + await**

```
async function loadusers_async_await() {
        let url = '< Your URL Here>';

    try {
        let response = await fetch(url);
        let data = await response.json();

        let str = '';
        for (let curr of data.results) {
            str += `<Your html string here> < ${curr.key1.key2...} >`
        }
        document.querySelector('#mydiv').innerHTML = str;
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log('there was an error', err);

    }
}
```