# TypeError Failed to fetch when doing GET request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I have an endpoint I created in node.js that gets and returns some data.

I would like to get this data in my react frontend.

This is what I have in my backend:

```
app.get('/retrieveQuestion', (req, res) => {
    axios.get("https://data.mongodb-api.com/app/data-pkrpq/endpoint/getEasyChallenge",{
        headers: {
            'api-key': process.env.APIKEY
        }
    }).then((resp) =>{
        res.send({ challenge: resp.data })
    })
});
```

When I try to do a `GET` request on this endpoint I get the data I expect.

When I try to `GET` this data in my frontend:

```
function getEasyQuestion(){
    axios.defaults.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/retrieveQuestion")
    .then((res) =>{
        console.log('res',res)
    })
}
```

I get the error:

```
GET http://localhost:5000/retrieveQuestion net::ERR_FAILED 200
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at getEasyQuestion (Editor.js:72:1)
```

I noticed that I get this error before the error mentioned above:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/retrieveQuestion' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch and Cors error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42754388/uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-failed-to-fetch-and-cors-error)

Comment: Is the error with the backend Mongo request, or with the FE actually receiving it? Can you print `resp.data` on the BE and check it's there as expected. Have you checked stuff like `https` vs `http` in your request URL? If you Google it there's a whole bunch of potential reasons for that error, gotta narrow it down.

Comment: @Jayce444 Backend prints the data as expected. I can `GET` the data from postman using the exact same URL, it's running in local so http

Comment: @Emm again, without some more info we could be missing potential causes. Are you using cors middleware, e.g. `app.use(cors());`? Have you checked that the response content type header that the back end is sending vs what browser expects are the same, i.e. JSON? Have you tried the Express JSON method? i.e. `res.json({ challenge: resp.data })`

Comment: @Jayce444 Not sure if it's helpful, but also included in the question this error seems to be the root cause of everything else:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/retrieveQuestion' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: @Jayce444 I am not using cors middleware and I have tried using the Express JSON method

Answer (score 0):

i think you are trying to access data from **http** url to **https** (secure) page. which isn't allowed.

try to host this website or you can use temporary service like [ngrok](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrok)

use `npm i ngrok`